# How do I register a callback for nested script tag appends in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, include, dom-events

I'm trying to hack a 3rd party JavaScript pop-up and I need to somehow register a callback so I can take action after it has loaded. I have code on my page that looks like this:

```
document.write('<' + 'script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://www.notmydomain.com/include.js"><\/script>');
```

the source for include.js looks like this:

```
document.write('<' + 'script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://www.notmydomain.com/anotherinclude.js?id=uniqueidicantreplicate"><\/script>');
```

anotherinclude.js writes some new divs to the DOM and I want to interact with them.

I'm not serving any of the .js files off my domain, I don't have control over their contents, their contents may occasionally change, and there are some unique identifiers in the js that change every time the file is downloaded that I can't spoof.

How do I register a callback so that I can take action when the new DOM elements are loaded?

Comment: Does the new code show up in an iframe or a div on a site under a domain you actually control (i.e., does it affect a DOM you can currently interact with yourself?)

Comment: The new code adds a div, then puts an iFrame in that div. What I really need to do is take action when the div is set to display: none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, DOM2 and DOM4 provide some tools to listen for tree changes, and you could use these, but browser support is inconsistent. Specifically, I'm talking about the [MutationEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120614/#events-MutationEvent) (DOM2) and [MutationObserver](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutationobserver) (DOM4) interfaces. Besides limited browser support, you'll need to watch out for performance issues with MutationEvent.